# Converting a Views SQL query with INNER JOIN to an EntityQuery

Tags: entities, database

I'm trying to create a custom JSON:API resource that returns the entities that have been flagged by a user.  (The Flag module does not offer a way to get this out of the box.)

I used Views to build a query to show all terms flagged by the user:

```
SELECT taxonomy_term_field_data.tid AS tid, flagging_taxonomy_term_field_data.id AS flagging_taxonomy_term_field_data_id
FROM
{taxonomy_term_field_data} taxonomy_term_field_data
INNER JOIN {flagging} flagging_taxonomy_term_field_data ON taxonomy_term_field_data.tid = flagging_taxonomy_term_field_data.entity_id AND (flagging_taxonomy_term_field_data.flag_id = 'MY_FLAG' AND flagging_taxonomy_term_field_data.uid = 'MY_UID')
```

Then, I installed the [JSON:API Resources](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources) module and configured a custom resource.

However, JSON:API uses EntityQuery, not regular SQL queries.

So based on my very limited knowledge of SQL, I wrote a basic query to get all the terms:

```
    $query = $this->getEntityQuery('taxonomy_term')
      ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), 'MY_VOCABULARY');
```

Now I want to restrict this to the terms that have been flagged by the user.  How do I implement the INNER JOIN in the Views query in EntityQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [hook_query_TAG_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.2.x)

Sample code

```
$query = $this->getEntityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), 'MY_VOCABULARY')->addTag('join_flaging');

/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_query_join_flagging_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->addJoin("INNER","flagging","flg","taxonomy_term_field_data.tid = flg.entity_id AND (flg.flag_id='MY_FLAG' AND flg.uid='MY_UID')");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm awarding the bounty to you because your solution works without having to patch core.

Answer (score 2):

As the flagging_taxonomy_term is an entity, see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/-/blob/8.x-4.x/src/Entity/Flagging.php, according to [this change-record](https://www.drupal.org/node/1882418), JOINS are supported, for you like:

```
<?php
$query = Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  // $UPDATE: ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), 'MY_VOCABULARY') use vid as bundle:
  ->condition('vid', 'MY_VOCABULARY')
  ->condition('flagging.entity.flag_id', 'YOUR_FLAG')
  ->condition('flagging.entity.uid', 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code results in an error: `Error: Call to a member function getColumns() on bool in Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->addField() (line 253 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php).`

Comment: Give this patch a try -> https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2893747#comment-13886822

Comment: With the patch, a new error: `Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\Query\\QueryException: Invalid specifier 'flagging' in /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php:315` Since Flag doesn't support revisions, I tried [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2649268) but I got the same error.

Comment: @PatrickKenny it might just be `flagging` that's not quite right - try looking at the Field List admin report, try to locate the field which represents the relationship from the vocab to the flag, and replace `flagging` with that machine name

Comment: @Clive Unfortunately, changing `flagging` to the field name didn't work, either.

Comment: BTW - what's $entity_type->getKey('bundle') ? Try to hardcode this to "vid"